# Which indexes are recommended in this query?

Tags: indexing

I'm working with tpc-h benchmark in postgres and mysql (myisam and innodb), I have run all the queries correctly until now, but I have to run them again using indexes and so I can see if they help or not the execution time. My question is about Q2 which is as follows:

```
select
    s_acctbal,
    s_name,
    n_name,
    p_partkey,
    p_mfgr,
    s_address,
    s_phone,
    s_comment
from
    part,
    supplier,
    partsupp,
    nation,
    region
where
    p_partkey = ps_partkey
    and s_suppkey = ps_suppkey
    and p_size = 35
    and p_type like '%STEEL'
    and s_nationkey = n_nationkey
    and n_regionkey = r_regionkey
    and r_name = 'EUROPE'
    and ps_supplycost = (
        select
            min(ps_supplycost)
        from
            partsupp,
            supplier,
            nation,
            region
        where
            p_partkey = ps_partkey
            and s_suppkey = ps_suppkey
            and s_nationkey = n_nationkey
            and n_regionkey = r_regionkey
            and r_name = 'EUROPE'
    )
order by
    s_acctbal desc,
    n_name,
    s_name,
    p_partkey
```

`nation` and `regions` are small tables with 20 and 5 rows respectively, so they don't need an index, but the other tables are using the default index (the pk one), which indexes would be ok to speed up the query execution time?

Thank you!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago)